# tried my hands or tried my hand?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

What is wrong with this sentence?

I wrote -

I tried my hands again on my bicycle.

My teacher corrected to

I tried my hand again at riding my bicycle.

Confusion -

hands v.s hand - Why it is hand and not hands?

on my bicycle vs. at riding my bicycle?

Comment: *Try [one's] hand at X* is a fixed idiom; *hand* here has the figurative sense of "skill", so the idiom means "test [one's] skill at X". The figure is a [*metonymy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy).

Comment: What were you trying to say in the original phrase? "tried my hands" isn't meaningful literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Try my hand* is an idiom meaning to try to do something. You can read more about it here:

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/try+hand+at

*Try my hand**s*** is not an idiomatic expression, and if you say this, it might be a little confusing to people.